# Found shared references to a collection in Grails

Tags: grails

In my app, the user makes a search. That search gives back a list of people that can be hired for a duty. But, user can make more than one search for the same duty (say, i need two persons for this city, and three for that city). Every search makes a "Prepresupuesto", and every Prepresupuesto makes a "Cocontrato". All "Cocontrato" makes a "Contrato", and all "Prepresupuestos" makes a single "Presupuesto". And all together conforms the entire duty, called "Campaign" in the app.

When i am trying to save that "Cocontrato", I receive the exception. This is the code:

```
ArrayList<Prepresupuesto> prepresus=Prepresupuesto.findAllByCamp(campid)

        Presupuesto pres=new Presupuesto()

        for(int i=0;i<prepresus.size();i++){

            pres.prepresu.add(prepresus[i])

            pres.camp=Campaign.get(prepres.camp.id)

            pres.estado="Pending"

            total=total+prepresus[i].total

            crearCocontrato(prepresus[i])
            }
```

Method crearCocontrato():

```
public crearCocontrato(Prepresupuesto prep){
    Set <Azafata>azas=prep.azafatas
    Cocontrato cocon=new Cocontrato()
    cocon.contrato=con
    cocon.precio=prep.precio
    cocon.azafatas=azas
    cocon.total=prep.total
    cocon.horas=prep.horas
    cocon.horario=prep.horario
    cocon.localidad=prep.localidad
    cocon.fechaInicio=prep.fechaInicio
    cocon.fechaFin=prep.fechaFin
    cocon.presu=prep
    cocon.camp=prep.camp



    if(!(cocon.save(flush:true))){
        render (view:"fallos", model:[azafataInstance:cocon])

    }
}
```

The Exception is launched in the if.

Any help? I am a bit lost, I am a newcomer to Grails, and I think i don't understand completely the exception.

Thank you!

EDIT: The Exception:

```
Found shared references to a collection: com.publidirecta.Cocontrato.azafatas.     Stacktrace follows:
Message: Found shared references to a collection: com.publidirecta.Cocontrato.azafatas
Line | Method
->> 2448 | crearCocontrato in com.publidirecta.EntidadController$$ENmku0D2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   2394 | boton           in     ''
|    886 | runTask . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|    908 | run             in     ''
^    680 | run . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Please post the message of your exception, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably trying to save more than one entity (cocon) when both refer to the same collection. It's hard to detect that in this code you posted and it could be somewhere else, but I would say it's when you do this:

```
Set <Azafata>azas=prep.azafatas
cocon.presu=prep
```

Then when you save cocon, it points to the same collection that prep does. Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692871/found-shared-references-to-a-collection-org-hibernate-hibernateexception), that says the same thing.

A way out of this would be to add element by element to the list you want to copy to instead of sharing the reference by doing `a.list = b.list`.

[This](http://programming34m0.blogspot.com.br/2009/11/hibernate-exception-in-grails-when.html) can also help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Tiago, after diving a bit in the code (it is inherited code...) i found that the problem was what you are saying. I solved it by doing this:

```
ArrayList <Azafata> azas=new ArrayList<Azafata>()
    for(int i=0;i<prep.azafatas.size(); i++){
        azas.add(prep.azafatas.toArray()[i])
}
```

And everything was ok :) Thank you for your answer.