# Found shared references to a collection:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am facing this error in my entity class.

> Found shared references to a collection:`com.model.Parts.employees`

Below is my code in the Parts model class

```
@OneToMany

@JoinColumn(name="COMPASS_SKU", referencedColumnName="MANUF_PART_NUM")

private Set<Employee> employees;
```

How can I get rid of this error?

The stack trace:

> ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for
>   SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff87a50a79:-7b13082e:5429d17a:27,
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@10da269
>
> > : javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a
> >     collection: com.model.Parts.employees at
> >     org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
> >     [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redha

Comment: What error your are getting? Please put your error stacktrace code

Comment: Probably you are using same employee set in multiple instances of the Parts. Also, probably it's a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692871/found-shared-references-to-a-collection-org-hibernate-hibernateexception